# BroadCast Receiver Active only when activity is running else deactivated

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Hi i am using a broadcast receiver for location listening but this broadcast receiver is working only when activity is in foreground else when i am not using this app then receiver  is not active
here is code of activity  onCreate's method where i am registering my broadcast receiver

```
 PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



locationManager.addProximityAlert(

           latitude, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region

           longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region

           1000, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters

           -1, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no expiration

           proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected

      );

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT+s); 

     registerReceiver(new ProximityAlertReceiver(), filter);
```

and code for BroadcastReceiver is

```
public class ProximityAlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";


    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
SharedPreferences shared=context.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFS_NAME,0);


        Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
Double longitude=intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0);
Double latitude=intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude",0.0);

Intent in = new Intent(context,AlarmActivity.class);
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
in.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
in.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
Log.i("cont1", shared.getInt("count", 0)+"");
in.putExtra("count",shared.getInt("count", 0));
context.startActivity(in);
}

}
```

i read some where that register and unregister it in onResume and onPause method respectively but when i unregister it in onPause method then it get unregistered means it will not work i want my broadcast receiver to work for all the time.can you please suggest how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4):

If you want this works in background then, You need to add broadcast receiver in manifest file with Broadcast receiver class.

like this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

You can use your own "MyReceiver".

Here in this case you dont need to register and unregistered. This will work automatically.

Comment: Yashdeep patel your answer is correct.Ritesh Mehandiratta try this answer.

Comment: @Ritesh Mehandiratta if this answer help you. Please select this as answer. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

if you want your broadcast receiver to run all teh time, yu need to register it from manifest file. 
from documentation: 
You can either dynamically register an instance of this class with Context.registerReceiver() or statically publish an implementation through the  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 0):

> First of you are defined mainfest so app also not running they
>   broadcast receiver work.. so you can handle this type of broadcast
>   using a PackageManager and get package name if is enable or disable
>   you can check and run your brodcast

Answer (score 0):

i think Service class will help you , try to implement .... in background for infinity times and when ever your service will find that something is changed then it will send some broadcast . to you :)