# BroadCast Receiver is not Working

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Hi i asked a question before related to Broadcast [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872686/broadcast-receiver-active-only-when-activity-is-running-else-deactivated)

they suggest me to add broadcast receiver class in Manifest file and then register its instances in Activity's onCreate method
so here is code of my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.riteshmapsapplicationdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="Tring On Train"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
          <uses-library android:required="true" 
                 android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Tring On Train" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     <activity
         android:name=".AlarmActivity"
         android:label="Alarm" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Address_List_Activity"
            android:label="Saved Locations" />
         <receiver android:name=".ProximityAlertReceiver" >

        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is code segment of onCreate's method where i am registering instances of BroadCast Receiver class.

```
String s=System.currentTimeMillis()+"";

  PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



locationManager.addProximityAlert(

           latitude, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region

           longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region

           1000, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters

           -1, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no expiration

           proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected

      );

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT+s); 

     registerReceiver(new ProximityAlertReceiver(), filter);
```

and code of My ProximityAlert class is

```
public class ProximityAlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";


    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
SharedPreferences shared=context.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFS_NAME,0);


        Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
Double longitude=intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0);
Double latitude=intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude",0.0);

Intent in = new Intent(context,AlarmActivity.class);
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
in.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
in.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
Log.i("cont1", shared.getInt("count", 0)+"");
in.putExtra("count",shared.getInt("count", 0));
context.startActivity(in);
}

}
```

now last time Broadcast receiver working when activity is in foreground but this time Broadcast receiver is not working in any situation can any one please notify me where i am wrong??

Comment: Are you registering receiver and intent in onCreate() of activity?

Comment: yes i am creting intent for PendingIntent proximityIntent and registering a receiver with a filter but problem is this register unregistered after i press back button.i want this receiver to work for always please check this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872686/broadcast-receiver-active-only-when-activity-is-running-else-deactivated.please help if u can.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to receive broadcasts when not running Activity in foreground. For that you need to add valid `intent-filter` to your `receiver` in **AndroidManifest.xml**

For example:

```
<receiver android:name=".ProximityAlertReceiver" >
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.your.app.example_filter_1" />
        <action android:name="com.your.app.example_filter_2" />
        <!-- etc -->
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I don't believe that's necessary if you register it programmatically.

Comment: but he is expecting to receiver those filters when not in activity, that means the receiver in android-manifest should kick-in and in order to work that, he must need to define those filters in the manifest

Comment: i cant declare Intent Filter in manifest because they are dynamically generated by user they are not static same in this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html he also didn't declare intent-filter in manifest in last example.please tell whats wrong in code when i registering them dynamically?

Comment: if you cant add intent-filters then you dont need to define your receiver at all in manifest. Simply register it within your activity and it will work only if your Activity is in foreground.

Comment: @Waqas i want to register it in my activity and it should work for all the time.is it possible or not??

Answer (score 0):

Your not defined what type of broadcast receiver you want to receive..try to add intent-filter    in the manifest receiver tag. The the android will send you.

Comment: i cant declare Intent Filter in manifest because they are dynamically generated by user they are not static same in this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html he also didn't declare intent-filter in manifest in last example.please tell whats wrong in code when i registering them dynamically?

Comment: <receiver
            android:name="MyReciverClass" 
            >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>.....this is intent-filter will send a broadcast when you receive a sms